# Minimum cost to empty an array by repeatedly removing first and middle, first and last, or middle and last elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, language-agnostic

This question was asked to me in an interview, and I was unable to come up with an optimal solution.

### Question

> Given an ***even*** size array, we can perform any ***operation*** on the array, until the array becomes empty such that the overall ***cost*** should be ***minimum***.
>
> **Operations:**
>
> 1. remove first and last element => cost will be **gcd(first, last)**
> 2. remove first and middle element => cost will be **gcd(first, middle)**
> 3. remove middle and last element => cost will be **gcd(middle, last)**

**Note:**

- *In an even size array, there are two middle elements. So, consider the second middle element as the middle element.*
- *gcd(x,y) stands for [Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20greatest%20common,divides%20each%20of%20the%20integers.) between x and y*

**Example:**

Input: [2, 4, 8, 6]

Output: 4

Explanation:

- *In the first operation remove the first and middle element, cost = gcd(2,8) = 2*
- *In the second operation remove 4 and 6, cost = gcd(4,6) = 2*
- *Total cost = 2+2 = 4*

---

Comment: What will be __middle__ element for the __even__ size array?

Comment: OK,it just needs to be defined. What if two or three pairs have equal `gcd`?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg you can take either of them. It doesn't matter unless the overall cost is minimum.

Comment: What strategy does your algorithm use int this situation?

Comment: Are you supposed to pick a new "operation" in every step, or always apply the same "operation"?

Comment: @Joni We can use any of them such that the cost of that operation is minimum than others.

Comment: You are describing a *greedy algorithm*. Greedy algorithms are rarely optimal. Given this input {2,1000,1000,5}, can you convince yourself that your solution is optimal?

Comment: @Kakashi `My approach was to compare all the 3 operation cost, whichever is minimum perform that until the array is empty. ` - please elaborate. It's not clear what exactly you're doing.

Comment: @Anatolii I have added my sample code. but that doesn't seem to work when I dry run it for some input.

Comment: Practically, I would say, what is the cost of determining the optimal cost? is it worth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of the order we perform the operations, the state of the list can be described with four pointers that describe exactly the two remaining, contiguous sections of the list.

These pointers are related by a specific set of rules that restrict which states are possible to achieve. I would start with using the four pointer combination and conduct recursion with memoised state.

We can reduce the state further by observing that the two contiguous sections can differ in length by either 0 or 2. I'll try to update this answer later.

JavaScript code (random test in Python against brute force available [here](https://replit.com/@gl_dbrqn/NaiveSiennaEmulators#main.py)):

```js
function gcd(x, y){
  while(y)
    [x, y] = [y, x % y];
  return x;
}

function f(A){
  const memo = {};
  const n = A.length;
  const mid = n / 2;
  
  function g(l0, l1, r0, r1){
    const key = String([l0, l1, r0, r1]);

    if (memo.hasOwnProperty(key))
      return memo[key];
    
    const len_l = l1 - l0 + 1;
    const len_r = r1 - r0 + 1;

    if (len_l + len_r == 2){
      if (len_r && len_l)
        return gcd(A[l0], A[r0]);
      else if (len_l)
        return gcd(A[l0], A[l0 + 1]);
      else
        return gcd(A[r0], A[r0 + 1]);
    }

    let a = A[l0];
    let b = A[r1];

    const outer = gcd(a, b) + g(l0 + 1, l1, r0, r1 - 1);

    if (len_r >= len_l)
      var mid = r0 + (len_l + len_r) / 2 - len_l;
    else
      var mid = l0 + (len_l + len_r) / 2;

    b = A[mid];
    
    const _l1 = l1 - (mid == l1 ? 1 : 0);
    const _r0 = r0 + (mid == r0 ? 1 : 0);

    const left = gcd(a, b) + g(l0 + 1, _l1, _r0, r1);

    a = A[r1];

    const right = gcd(b, a) + g(l0, _l1, _r0, r1 - 1);

    return memo[key] = Math.min(outer, left, right);
  }
  
  return g(0, mid - 1, mid, n - 1);
}

let A = [2, 4, 8, 6];
console.log(JSON.stringify(A));
console.log(f(A));

A = [8,5,21,10,25,9]
console.log(JSON.stringify(A));
console.log(f(A));

const n = 200;
A = [];

for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
  A.push(i + 1);

console.log(JSON.stringify(A));
console.log(f(A));
```

Comment: +1 for the answer and effort, but I did some dry run with few examples. Your code returns `4` for the input `[8,5,21,10,25,9]` while it should return 3.
[8,5,21,10,25,9] => gcd(10,9) = 1, remaining [8,5,21,25] => gcd(21,25) = 1, remaining [8,5] => gcd(8,5) = 1. Total = 3.

Comment: @Kakashi I think I figured out how to reduce the state further. The key is this line, `const _l1 = l1 - (mid == l1 ? 1 : 0);`, and the next where we see mid either equals l1 or r0. That means the two sections can differ in length by either 0 or 2.

Comment: @Kakashi that reduces the search space to O(n^3). Did the interviewer provide an expected complexity for the solution?

Comment: @גלעדברקן you're right. No additional array s needed. +1